# Edges to SKSpriteNodes disappear from graph after I change the nodes' texture

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm making a game with SpriteKit and my SKSpriteNodes sometimes disappear from my graph after I change the texture of my nodes.

My game uses vertices (SKSpriteNodes) and edges, which I store in an adjacency list

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *vertices;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *edges;
```

My game runs fine, except when I change the texture of my vertex to mark a change of state

```
SKTexture *visitedHouse = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"house-v"];
[vertex setTexture:visitedHouse];
```

Then sometimes, edges mysteriously disappear. The number of edges and vertices stays the same, however the edge isn't connected to the vertex with the new texture anymore. i.e.  `[[self.edges objectForKey:currentVertex] containsObject:vertex]` returns  `false`. This never happens if I don't change the texture.

Do you guys know what might cause this? Do changes of texture affect the location of my nodes in memory?

**Edit:**

The game is about finding a Hamiltonian Cycle in a graph, i.e. find a path so that you, `self.nathan`, visit every vertex once and then return to the starting vertex.

This is the code I use to generate the graph and update the graph

**Graph Generation**

```
-(void)generateGraph:(NSInteger)numOfVertices {
```

...grid generation and positioning code omitted...

```
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfVertices; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *vertex;
    if (i == 0) {
      SKTexture *houseTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"house-h"];
      vertex = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:houseTexture];
    } else {
      SKTexture *houseTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"house-u"];
      vertex = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:houseTexture];
    }

    //positioning
```

...positioning code omitted...

```
    vertex.position = position;
    [self.playground addChild:vertex];
    [self.vertices addObject:vertex];

    //cycle creation
    if (i > 0) {
      SKSpriteNode *previousVertex = self.vertices[i - 1];
      [self.edges setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[previousVertex]] forKey:vertex];
      [[self.edges objectForKey:previousVertex] addObject:vertex];

    } else {
      [self.edges setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:vertex];
    }
  }
  [[self.edges objectForKey:self.vertices[0]] addObject:self.vertices[numOfVertices - 1]];
  [[self.edges objectForKey:self.vertices[numOfVertices - 1]] addObject:self.vertices[0]];

  //noise edges

  NSInteger numOfNoiseEdges = numOfVertices / 2;

  for (int i = 0; i < numOfNoiseEdges; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *originVertex = self.vertices[i];
    NSMutableArray *adjacent = [self.edges objectForKey:originVertex];

    while (1) {
      SKSpriteNode *newAdjacent = self.vertices[arc4random() % numOfVertices];
      if (![adjacent containsObject:newAdjacent]) {
        [adjacent addObject:newAdjacent];
        [[self.edges objectForKey:newAdjacent] addObject:originVertex];
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  [self.visitedVertices addObject:self.vertices[0]];
}
```

**Updates when I visit a vertex**

```
- (void)visitVertex:(SKSpriteNode *)vertex {
  SKSpriteNode *currentVertex = [self.visitedVertices lastObject];
  CGPoint targetPoint = vertex.position;
  CGPoint currentPosition = currentVertex.position;
  CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(targetPoint.x - currentPosition.x, targetPoint.y - currentPosition.y);
  CGFloat length = sqrtf(offset.x * offset.x + offset.y * offset.y);
  CGFloat duration = length / POINTS_PER_SEC;
  [self.visitedVertices addObject:vertex];

  SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1.0 duration:FADE_IN_DURATION];
  SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:targetPoint duration:duration];
  SKAction *leaveGroup = [SKAction group:@[fadeIn, moveAction]];
  SKAction *fadeOut = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.0 duration:FADE_OUT_DURATION];
  SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence :@[leaveGroup, fadeOut]];
  [self.nathan runAction:sequence completion:^{
    [self checkWin];
   SKTexture *visitedHouse = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"house-v"];
   [vertex setTexture:visitedHouse];
  }];
}
```

**and this is the portion of code that acts inconsistently**. If I change the texture, it sometimes can't find the adjacent vertex. i.e. `[[self.edges objectForKey:currentVertex] containsObject:vertex]` returns `false` even though it shouldn't

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    SKSpriteNode *currentVertex = [self.visitedVertices lastObject];
    for (SKSpriteNode *vertex in self.vertices) {
      touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.playground];

      if ([vertex containsPoint:touchPoint] && [currentVertex containsPoint:self.nathan.position]) {
        if ([[self.edges objectForKey:currentVertex] containsObject:vertex]) {
          if (![self.visitedVertices containsObject:vertex] ||
              ([self.visitedVertices count] == [self.vertices count] && vertex == self.visitedVertices[0])) {
            [self visitVertex:vertex];
            break;

          } else {
            NSLog(@"already visited");
          }
        } else {
          NSLog(@"no edge");
        }
      } else {
        NSLog(@"miss touch");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: there's not enough code (context) to understand the problem, please add more relevant code (ie how and why you add/remove items to the arrays/dictionaries). Specifically it's unclear whether objectForKey or containsObject returns nil.

Comment: I added all the relevant code, hope it's not too much. Thanks a lot!